# Why use AWS Access Keys instead of IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-iam

1. Why are AWS access keys (access key ID and secret access key) complex i.e. lengthy and unreadable unlike console access credentials? A key if its simple or complex once stolen doesn't help and so why not keep it simple ?
2. Apart from logging into AWS CLI, what are the scenarios where only access keys (access key ID and secret access key) can help and where the recommended best practice of using roles is not practical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not like to guess the inner thoughts of the people who design AWS authentication, but a complex secret improves the security by making it more difficult to guess. It would also increase the complexity of data encoded with the key, making it harder to reverse-engineer. Plus, nobody ever types it, so there is no need to have a short secret.

The Access Key and Secret Key is used for *every* API request to AWS. This can come from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), or any software created with an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/). In fact, the AWS CLI is just a Python program that uses the AWS SDK for Python (called `boto3`).

**IAM Roles** can be assigned to Amazon EC2 instances. This will then provide a temporary Access Key and Secret Key to an instance (see [Retrieving Security Credentials from Instance Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials)). So, roles are just a secure way of providing an Access Key, but the Access Key is still used.

An IAM Role can also be *assumed* to obtain temporary access to resources, but calling the `AssumeRole()` command also requires an Access Key to authenticate and prove the right to assume the role.

The only time that an Access Key and Secret Key are not required is for login to the AWS Management Console, but the console is still using an Access Key to call the AWS API.

**Bottom line:** An Access Key and Secret Key is required to access AWS resources.

Comment: "The Access Key and Secret Key is used for every API request to AWS" - I read somewhere that even the requests made via web console will involve access keys (like you said, probably for complex data encoding than would have been possible through a much simpler username and password) although this is handled implicitly by AWS. For web console login, nobody would want to remember a complex access key id and secret key to memorize and probably that is why AWS left it to users - your thoughts ?

Comment: The AWS management console certainly does make calls on behalf of users. You can see this if you look at the CloudTrail logs where actions are performed via the console. However, the console can be used even if the user has not allocated an Access Key + Secret Key. Think of it is a 'different' way to authenticate to AWS.

Comment: Thanks John, I believe that is to say that API requests from web console will use Access Key + Secret Key but if you are just logging in and only navigating through the services, no Access Key + Secret Key is used - right?

Comment: The AWS console has some other form of authentication, so it is not exactly the same as AK + SK. Even if a user does not have an AK + SK assigned, they can still use the console. Even just viewing information in the console requires API calls that are authenticated. I recommend that you take a look at CloudTrail records generated by activity in the console and you'll see how the access is classified.